# SoapUI, is there a way to copy and paste test steps?

Tags: soapui

I am working on a test suite, which involves number of test cases having common test steps (Not in the same order, so data driven  or running on a loop is not an option here).

In writing these tests the only option I can see of is to clone the test steps. To clone a tests step it involves at least 5 mouse actions to be carried out, which is annoying when it comes to large number of tests.

Is the re a way that we can just copy and paste / drag and drop the steps so that they are get copied in to ?

I know other option would be editing the xml, which again have to be done carefully. But don't want to do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold Ctrl and use drag and drop. This will copy the test step with only one question asked, about the test step name. That dialog could be closed by clicking OK or pressing enter.